# Does python have counterparts of digits() and vpa() function in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, sympy

Suppose I need the calculation precision to be very high, or the program I am dealing with is very sensitive to numerical errors. In Matlab, I can do like this:

```
d = 30;
digits(d);
t = vpa(1);
H = vpa(zeros(2, 2));
H(2, 1) = t;
H(1, 2) = t;
eigenvalues = vpa(eig(H));
```

Of course the above program is very simple, but the idea is the same for larger matrix and more variables case.

How to rewrite this in python, I can't find any counterparts in python packages.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?

Comment: There is also http://mpmath.org/

Comment: If you're happy with just 30 digits precision [numpy](https://numpy.org/) can work with 128 bit floats (np.float128 aka np.longdouble).

Comment: @JohanC does mpmath supports matrix diagnonalize? BTW, I've tried 128 bit floats, not enough to eliminate the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It looks like digits() function. I don't know if I can pass it to numpy without loosing precision, since I need to diagonalize a matrix in the end.

Comment: Maybe via http://mpmath.org/doc/current/matrices.html#the-symmetric-eigenvalue-problem ?

Comment: @JohanC Looks hopeful, I'll learn and try it and give you feedback later.

Comment: @JohanC It works. One flaw is that the diagonalization is not automatically paralleled, which is makes it pretty slow compared with numpy.

Answer (score 2):

SymPy does calculations symbolically and you can request evaluation to arbitrary precision.

```
>>> A
Matrix([
[ 1,  1,  1,  1, 0],
[-1,  1,  1,  1, 1],
[ 0, -1,  1,  1, 1],
[ 0,  0, -1,  1, 1],
[ 0,  0,  0, -1, 1]])
>>> evals = solve(A.charpoly().as_expr())
>>> evals[0].n(30)
1.44482461851856062804340583653
```

In this case, the 5th order polynomial is in a form that is not recognized by the `eigenvals` routine so A.eigenvals() will generate an error. But if your matrix doesn't present such difficulties it may be possible to generate the eigenvalues more directly:

```
>>> A = Matrix([[75, 74], [73,  4]])
>>> _.eigenvals()
{79/2 - 9*sqrt(329)/2: 1, 79/2 + 9*sqrt(329)/2: 1}
>>> list(_.keys())[0]
79/2 - 9*sqrt(329)/2
>>> _.n(30)
-42.1226071624767447920482826638
```

Comment: You can use RootOf on the characteristic polynomial to numerically evaluate it even if it can't be represented in closed form. But it would probably be useful for SymPy to have a symbolic Eigenvalues object that could be numerically evaluated with mpmath's eigenvalue solver without having to compute the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: `solve` automatically returns RootOf instances in the case of the 5x5 case above.

Comment: Questions: 1.what do you mean "In this case, the 5th order polynomial is in a form that is not recognized by the eigenvals routine"? 2. what are the values on the left and right of ':' in "
{79/2 - 9*sqrt(329)/2: 1, 79/2 + 9*sqrt(329)/2: 1}"

Comment: The roots of the 5th order polynomial cannot be expressed in terms of radicals and the eigenvals routine does not currently handle such polynomials. The keys of the dictionary are the roots and the values (right of the colon) are the multiplicities. So in the case given, there are two roots, each with a multiplicity of 1.